# creating a xml in android

Tags: android, xml

I want to  create a new xml file in android.my code is like below.It didn't work

```
File newxmlfile = new File("C:/Users/yunus.oksuz/Desktop/xmlFile.xml");
try
{
newxmlfile.createNewFile();
Toast msg = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "file was created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
msg.show();
}
catch(IOException e)
{
Log.e("IOException", "exception in createNewFile() method");
}
```

Comment: I don't wanna ask this, but are u referring to a xml file stored in your PC?!!

Comment: I know ıt can be impossible but when I was change path, didnt work.

File newxmlfile = new File("/data/com.itwine/xmlFile.xml");

Answer (score 0):

First thing to know, you cannot even think about having a file in your PC and trying to refer it to your Android application project. They both are totally different.

let me explain the reason.

Consider you have the app installed in a phone, how do you think you can simply access your PC to which you are no more connected. This is not a regular java project you are working on. Android is totally different.

I will tell how it works. Open a emulator and wait for it to load. now,

Go to `DDMs-> File Explorer`

You will be able to see a folder by name "mnt" or "sdcard". Click on it. And now on the top right corner you will have three icons , one to push a file to sdcard and one to delete from sdcard and also one to pull a file from sdcard.

So click on the push a file icon and select your file and copy it to sdcard.

Now you have your file in sdcard. here you have to learn how to read a file from sdcard.

And I am sure there are so many examples available on internet on how you can read a file from sdcard.

Hope this will help you to get it started.

Comment: I clicked push a file to sdcard but ıt was failed. "Failed to push selection: Local path doesn't exist."

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can create your xml file.

```
File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/yourxmlfilename.xml");

// If file does not exist, clear log count
if(!f.exists())
    f.createNewFile();
```

Comment: well... did you try my solution at least?

Comment: I know that but dont know how to save xml files on emulator